# Jenkins Pipeline couldn't init the repo (Windows controller, Mac agent)

Tags: git, jenkins, cicd

I have a Jenkins controller machine that runs Windows and an agent machine that runs on MacOS. Both machines have git installed.
If I type `where git` in my Mac's terminal, I get this output: `/usr/bin/git`.

**My goal is:** I'm trying to check out the 'team-ci' repo into the workspace of the Pipeline Project.

The issue is that if I do it using

```java
git branch: 'main',
        credentialsId: "defaultssh",
        url: "git@global.com:team/team-ci.git"
```

, then it tries to check out the 'main' branch using the Windows executable, so instead, I opted out for the `checkout` method.

Here's what the "Git installations" in "Global Tool Configuration" look like:

[image: Git installations in Global Tool Configuration Jenkins]

I wrote this pipeline code:

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'mac1'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Execute') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def branch = '*/main'
                    def credentialsId = 'defaultssh'
                    def projectUrl = "git@global.company.gitlab.com:team/team-ci.git"
                    def gitTool = isUnix() ? 'git_mac' : 'git_win'
                    echo "gitTool: " + gitTool
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: branch]],
                                gitTool: gitTool, 
                                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: credentialsId, url: projectUrl]]
                            ])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run this Pipeline Project, it outputs these exceptions in the console:

```
13:14:19  gitTool: git_mac
13:14:19  [Pipeline] checkout
13:14:19  The recommended git tool is: NONE
13:14:19  using credential defaultssh
13:14:19  Cloning the remote Git repository
13:14:19  ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:14:19  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /Library/Automation/jenkins/workspace/mac_pipeline_project
13:14:19  Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: /usr/bin/git init /Library/Automation/jenkins/workspace/mac_pipeline_project
13:14:19  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Automation/jenkins/workspace/" (in directory "/Library/Automation/jenkins/workspace/mac_pipeline_project"): error=13, Permission denied
13:35:19  Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
13:35:20  ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

What can I do to successfully clone the 'team-ci' project?

Comment: Regarding the last error is from the hudson that doesn't have the permission to write in the directory: `/Library/Automation/jenkins/workspace/mac_pipeline_project` ... you would need to check your filesystem permissions and make sure that the agent that runs the script have write permissiomns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to the Dashboard/Manage Jenkins/Nodes/mac1 and change the "Tool locations" value from "/Library/Automation/jenkins/workspace/" to "/usr/bin/git" under the "(Git) git_mac" tool.